# How do I use the hash :condition on a .find for a nil? method in Rails (has_one relationship)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find, null

I want to find all Contacts where the value of their :has_one relationship to :contact_status does not have a value (does that mean nil?)

I created an   `alias_attribute :status, :status_contact`

Can I do something along the lines of:

```
contacts = Contact.find(:all, :conditions => {:contact_status => nil }, :include => {:status_contact} )
```

I'm not sure exactly how nil works.  Basically, I don't assign any value to it, it is just a :has_one relationship.

**EDIT: Sounds like contacts should be a belongs_to relationship so making change**
From the comments, it sounds like Contacts should actually have a belongs_to relationship to status_contacts which in turn 'has_one' with Contacts.

I am using Searchlogic to create named_scopes...I *think* it solves the problem, anyone familiar with that?

However, there are times the user can assign a value to that.  I don't want those to come up in the find.

Currently get this error:

SQLite3::SQLException: near ".": syntax error: SELECT "contacts"."id" AS t0_r0, "contacts"."first_name" AS
t0_r1, "contacts"."last_name" AS t0_r2, "contacts"."title" AS t0_r3, "contacts"."phone" AS t0_r4, "contacts
"."fax" AS t0_r5, "contacts"."email" AS t0_r6, "contacts"."company" AS t0_r7, "contacts"."created_at" AS t0
_r8, "contacts"."updated_at" AS t0_r9, "contacts"."campaign_id" AS t0_r10, "contacts"."date_entered" AS t0_
r11, "contacts"."company_id" AS t0_r12, "contacts"."address_id" AS t0_r13, "contacts"."vcard_file_name" AS
t0_r14, "contacts"."vcard_content_type" AS t0_r15, "contacts"."vcard_file_size" AS t0_r16, "contacts"."vcar
d_updated_at" AS t0_r17, "contacts"."direct" AS t0_r18, "contacts"."sugarcrm" AS t0_r19, "status_contacts".
"id" AS t1_r0, "status_contacts"."status" AS t1_r1, "status_contacts"."contact_id" AS t1_r2, "status_contac
ts"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "status_contacts"."updated_at" AS t1_r4 FROM "contacts"  LEFT OUTER JOIN "status
_contacts" ON status_contacts.contact_id = contacts.id WHERE (:status_contact.status = NULL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error doesn't fit the code you are showing.
I guess you are doing something like

```
:conditions => ['status = ?', nil]
```

but what you should be checking is not the `status`, which is the linked object. It is how you would check it in ruby-code, but not in sql.

Inside your table, you would have a field called `status_contact_id`, and when that field is `NULL` (the database equivalent of `nil`) then it has no relation.

So you would indeed need to do something like

```
contacts = Contact.find(:all, :conditions => "status_contact_id IS NULL")
```

[EDIT] Since you are using a `has_one` relation, totally read over that, the foreign key is indeed defined in the `status_contacts` table. But, to query the items not having any status_contacts gets a bit more complicated.

In sql, you would do something like

```
select * from contacts where id not in (select contact_id from status_contacts)
```

and I would translate that to ruby like this:

```
contacts = Contacts.find_by_sql("select * from contacts where id not in (select contact_id from status_contacts)"
```

Personally i can't think of a better way right now.

Comment: Hmmm...maybe I have it backwards.  I don't have a status_contact_id ... my status_contact table does have a contact_id .... and it appears to be working....

Comment: contact has_one status_contact -- does that mean the one that has_one has the foreign key?  And I remote the foreign_key from status_contact?

Comment: this is what I found, it sounds like the belongs_to should have the foreign key?  http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/1/15/basic-rails-association-cardinality

Comment: Oops, a `has_one` relationship! I updated my answer to reflect that option.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
contacts = Contact.find(:all, :conditions => "status_contact_id IS NULL")
```

assuming your fk column is contacts.status_contact_id

**UPDATE:** nathanvda is correct; Also, I think you can do it without find_by_sql - *untested...*

```
contacts = Contact.find(:all, 
    :conditions => "contacts.id NOT IN (select contact_id from status_contacts)"   
)
```

**NOTE:** I still think you really want to use Contact with belongs_to :status_contact

Comment: Hi, shouldn't the record with the belongs_to have teh foreign key?  http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/1/15/basic-rails-association-cardinality

Comment: yes you are correct, after looking at your sql error I can see the schema now - my initial thought is that the has_one is not the ideal relationship to use for this case; unless you have a unique status_contact per contact, which I doubt is the case

Comment: no it's not unique....so it should be the other way around, contact belongs_to status_contact?

Comment: I 'think' contact belongs_to status_contact would work better in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the version of Rails, I mostly work in 2.3.5, but I believe "conditions", in this context, is meant to be a "SQL-like fragment."

Typically you'd do something like

```
contacts = Contact.find(:all, :include => :contact_status, :conditions => ["contact_status.status = ?", nil])
```

Also, `nil` in Ruby means completely devoid of value. It stores nothing. [], an empty array, will return false if you send it the message `nil?`, it will respond true to the message `empty?` however.

Comment: I am using 2.3.5...does the "hash" version work as well similar to what I put in?

Comment: The hash will work to specify fields and their values, I'm not sure if it'll work for an alias or not. Though I can't imagine why it wouldn't.

Comment: it knows because of the has_one associate to join with teh contact_status.contact_id?

Comment: `["contact_status.status = ?", nil]` translates to `contact_status = NULL` which is **always** false, because NULL = NULL => false in SQL.